# How to change route param without detecting changing route?

Tags: angular

What i want is to change specific route param but that is not detected as changing route. Any suggestion? 
I have this route : 
`www.test.com/evidention/21/1/0?test=1` and i want to change this 0 to 1 but if i use router.navigate it detects by router change and i dont want that. Any suggestion how can i avoid that?

Im using this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/evidencija/' + this.type + '/' + this.offerId + '/' + this.specId + '/' + this.active], { queryParams: { processId: this.processId }, queryParamsHandling: "merge" });
```

But problem is that in queryParams.subscribe i have some method that i dont want to call at that moment when i change only one param.

Comment: You could write some logic to compare the old parameters against the new parameters. Then if only 1 parameter changes, skip the rest of the subscribe method. An alternative would be to use a router snapshot instead of queryParams.subscribe. So not listen for router changes at all, but it seems like you want to detect changes some times.

Comment: yes i want to detect changes some time, but at some point i want to change route param that will not be detect by router changes